# JMeter Alter HTTP Headers During Test

Tags: http-headers, jmeter

I'm attempting to test an HTTP service with JMeter.  The HTTP service requires authentication through a simple bearer token mechanism.  I'm trying to proceed as follows:

1. POST authentication request
2. Store token as a variable
3. Set Authorization HTTP header to stored variable
4. Request protected resource(s)
5. Evaluate performance

So far I've been able to post the request, get the token, extract it with regex, save it to a variable, and assert that the variable is appropriately set.

The problem is getting the variable into the HTTP header.  In the "Header Manager" the value is set like this:

[image: Header Manager Attempt]

Unfortunately when the next requests are issued their authorization header has the value "Bearer ".  Searching around the internet led me to believe that headers are [configured before the thread starts](http://jmeter.512774.n5.nabble.com/HTTP-Header-Manager-uses-old-variable-values-td527582.html), which would explain the "Bearer "

My sampling/grouping/nesting is as follows:

[image: JMeter Nesting]

All the tests pass up to get restricted resource, which fails with a 400, since the authorization header is malformed.

I feel like I'm missing something really obvious, and/or approaching this problem the wrong way.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can dynamically construct your authorization header using [Beanshell PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PreProcessor) as follows:

1. Add **empty** HTTP Header Manager as a child of your request which requires authorization
2. Add Beanshell PreProcessor as a child of the same request with the following code:

   ```
   import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.Header;

   sampler.getHeaderManager().add(new Header("Authorization","Bearer " + vars.get("BEARER")));
   ```

This will construct fully dynamic header using `BEARER` variable.

- `sampler` is a shorthand to [HTTPSamplerProxy](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/sampler/HTTPSamplerProxy.html) class which gives access to parent Sampler instance
- `vars` is the instance of [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class which allows read/write access to all JMeter variables available within the bounds of current context (usually current Thread Group)

See [How to use BeanShell: JMeter's favorite built-in component](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide for more details on Beanshell scripting and kind of Beanshell cookbook.

Comment: If this exists within a loop, you may want to also remove before adding to prevent dups: `sampler.getHeaderManager().removeHeaderNamed("Authorization");`

Comment: This still doesn't work for me. I can add other headers using this mechanism, but I still cannot add an Authorization header. Using JMeter 3.0.

Comment: Ok, I got it working now. I was wrong. Looking at the request with wireshark shows that the header is being set, even though the UI doesn't show that.

Comment: for the record, there's no need for the HTTP Header Manager to be empty (as emphasized in the answer). The request should simply *have* an HTTP Header Manager, either empty or filled with values.

Comment: When I added a statement to remove, it not even setting the header. Sample code : ```sampler.getHeaderManager().removeHeaderNamed("Authorization");  sampler.getHeaderManager().add(new Header("Authorization","Bearer " + vars.get("BEARER")));``` Anyone can suggest me, what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 18):

You need to move your login under a controller. In my case, I used an Only Once Controller. Then after the controller you can add the HTTP Header Manager with the Authorization header as "Bearer ${BEARER}" and it will read your variable. This is better than the other answer because then you don't need to duplicate the BeanShell PreProcessor under every request. My tree looked like this:

[image: JMeter Tree]

Comment: This worked for me. However, how can I login only once and share the token across multiple threads without having to execute the Login Request again.

Answer (score -1):

in Beanshell preprocessor use the below code

import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.Header;
sampler.getHeaderManager().remove(0);

for more details refer :-

https://jmeterblogb.blogspot.in/2016/10/add-empty-header-in-jmeter-sample.html