# How to parameterize Bearer token authorization in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have a jmeter login script where user logs in and logs out. The detailed screenshots are attached below.

Request data is as attached:
[image: The request data content]

In the response date , the authorization token is generated:

[image]

And the regular expression for the same is as below: [image]

I am passing the value as parameter in 55/users:

[image]

When I'm running the script it is failing:
[image]

Here is the response data:

[image]

Comment: the error message says that the server wants this token in a HEADER, not as a URL parameter. Here's the solution you need to use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24542747/jmeter-alter-http-headers-during-test

Comment: i tried  but still the script does not work

Comment: sending bearer as a parameter of GET won't work either. Try to get that script working, or post question detailing what's not working in it

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Use Header Manager to pass the Token as a Header so you would have:

[image: Header Manager]

See for more details:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/43283700/460802

If you're looking to learn jmeter correctly, this [book](https://leanpub.com/master-jmeter-from-load-test-to-devops) will help you.

Answer (score 7):

A bit easier JMeter setup (login/get):

Thread Group

- HTTP Request, Body Data: { "Login":"some", "Password":"credentials" }

  - HTTP Header Manager: content-type application/json
  - JSON Extractor - Names of created variables: Token; JSON Path expression: tokenName (root level in my case)
- HTTP Request

  - HTTP Header Manager: content-type -> application/json; Authorization -> Bearer ${Token}
  - Response Assertion: Fields to Test = Response Code; Pattern Matching Rules = Equals, Not; Pattern to Test 401
- *View Results Tree* to check results

Local **IE Ajax** version in case...

```
<SCRIPT>
var baseUri = 'https://localhost:port';
var tokenUri = '/something';
var getUri = '/restrictedData';
var token;
var form = { "Login":"some", "Password":"credentials" };
postRequest(baseUri + tokenUri, form, gotToken)

function gotToken(progress) {
    var response = progress.srcElement;
    if (response.status != 200) {
        document.body.innerText = "Error:\n" + response.response;
        return;
    }
    token = JSON.parse(response.response);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(token));
    var restricted = getRequest(baseUri + getUri, token.tokenName, gotRestricted);
}
function gotRestricted(progress) {
    var jsonStr = progress.srcElement.response;
    var jsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonStr);
    document.body.innerText = JSON.stringify(token,null,2) + '\n\n' + JSON.stringify(jsonObj,null,2);
}
function getRequest(url, token, callback) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onloadend = callback;
    xhr.open('GET', url);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('contentType', 'application/json')
    if (token) xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
    xhr.send();
    return xhr;
}
function postRequest(url, body, callback) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onloadend = callback;
    xhr.open('POST', url);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')
    xhr.send(JSON.stringify(body));
    return xhr;
}
</SCRIPT>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you already have the bearer token and just want to use in in header manager then,
in HTTP HEADER MANAGER tab, put these values under NAME and VALUE column respectively.

```
Name: Authorization                        
Value: Bearer "add your actual token without quotes"
```

Answer (score 2):

Add Bearer `${token}` in HTTP Header Manager available under failing HTTP Request.

[image: image HTTP Request]

Answer (score 1):

I got cUrl from my API and then I imported it.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

use Authorization as parameter name and value should be
Bearer ${variable_name}

Answer (score 0):

Once you've extracted the token from the token API request, use this token in the HTTP Authorization Header manager for subsequent API's. Example below:

```
Header Name: Header Value Authorization: Bearer ${generated_token}
```

Where "generated_token" is a variable containing the extracted token.