# Capture the HTTP Header

Tags: http-headers, jmeter, blazemeter

I am trying to carry out a test as like it explained here: 
[JMeter Alter HTTP Headers During Test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24542747/jmeter-alter-http-headers-during-test?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Quote from above :

I'm attempting to test an HTTP service with JMeter. The HTTP service requires authentication through a simple bearer token mechanism. I'm trying to proceed as follows:

- POST authentication request Store token as a variable
- Set Authorization HTTP header to stored variable
- Request protected resource(s)
- Evaluate performance

When the POST occurs, I am not able to capture the bearer token. Its a header.

I tried the solution provided by Dmitri on that issue Or as Bennet tried with RegEx Extractor and HTTPs Manager.

I think I am doing something silly not to able to extract the token. Any thoughts how to extract the token?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) configuration is not correct, by default it:

- uses response **body** as a source therefore you need to switch it to look into response headers (red rectangle)
- looks up in **main sample** only, if your header is set after redirect it won't be processed (amber rectangle)

  Example configuration:

  [image: Regular Expression Extractor for Headers]

You can double check `${bearer}` variable value using [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener combination](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script).

Comment: tried all the options, still unable to extract the token. While debugging dont see bearer token anywhere. I am sure I am missing something really simple thing.

Comment: Update your question with screenshots of: View Results Tree listener on "Sample Result" tab showing the "bearer" header value you want to extract. 2. Regular Expression Extractor. Let me know via comment once done so I could take a look.

Comment: exactly that is what I am missing. I do not see bearer header. But for some reason when I do 'POST' method, it expects the bearer token as a request header. To summarize the app: user inputs log in credentials > bearer token is generated> this bearer token can be used throughout the test and then it expires. I do not see the bearer token in header (Jmeter). However if I run that in fiddler or firebug I can see it as the response header.  Not exactly sure why it behaves different in Jmeter vs Firebug's Net.

Comment: In that case I believe [How to Run Performance Tests on OAuth Secured Apps with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-performance-tests-oauth-secured-apps-jmeter) article will help

Comment: tried that from your earlier advice on other ticket. It did not work. I am super surprised on this issue. I am sure I am missing something very small. IT cant be this hard.

Comment: So finally got this wrapped up.  Steps taken were to use regular expression extractor and json extractor.