# jMeter not applying variable to header manager

Tags: json, jmeter

I'm using Apache JMeter 3.2 r1790748 on Mac.
I have a `setUp Thread Group` making an authentication call. The call works and outputs the tokens correctly. Now I need to pass that token to the `HTTP Header Manager` for all the calls I'm making.

First of all, here's my token json output:

```
{
    "access_token": "aaaaaa555555555",
    "token_type": "Access",
    "user_id": "5555"
}
```

**Here's what my `HTTP Header manager` looks like:**

1 value: `Authorization` : `Bearer ${access_token}`

**My network call:**

```
GET https://my_server.com/some_path

GET data:

[no cookies]

Request Headers:
Connection: close
Authorization: Bearer ${access_token}
Host: my_server.com
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.3 (Java/1.8.0_91)
```

As you can see, the variable `access_token` is not being replaced with the value from the setup call.

**What I've tried:**

BeanShell PostProcessor:

I created this script, and it actually parses and outputs the `access_token` properly:

```
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.Header;
import net.minidev.json.JSONObject;
import net.minidev.json.parser.JSONParser;


String jsonString = prev.getResponseDataAsString();
log.info("jsonString = " + jsonString);

JSONParser parser = new JSONParser(JSONParser.MODE_JSON_SIMPLE);
JSONObject json = (JSONObject) parser.parse(jsonString);

String access_token = json.getAsString("access_token");
log.info("access_token = " + access_token);
vars.put("access_token", access_token);
```

JSON Extractor:

```
Apply to: Main sample and sub-samples
Variable names: access_token
JSON Path expressions: access_token
Match No. (0 for Random): 1
Compute concatenation var (suffix _ALL): unchecked
Default Values: none
```

Any ideas as to why the header manager is not applying the value of the `access_token` result?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you set a variable in setUp Thread Group, you cannot use it in another thread groups, since thread groups don't share variables, only **properties**.

So in order to pass authentication, you need to save it as a property:

```
${__setProperty(access_token, ${access_token})};
```

In this example I am using value of *variable* named `access_token` (already set, but only available in setUp thread group) to set *property* with the same name, which will be available across thread groups. Or change BeanShell post-processor, add:

```
props.put("access_token", access_token);
```

And then in the other thread group, you retrieve it using `__P` or `__property` function:

```
${__P(access_token)}
```

Also keep in mind that HTTP Header Manager initializes before any thread starts, so you can't use variables there for that reason too. Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24542747/jmeter-alter-http-headers-during-test) for instance.

If you still see empty value, I recommend adding [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) (with both JMeter Properties and JMeter Variables enabled) in both thread groups, and checking where the breakage is (on saving or retrieving).

Comment: so, do I use ${__setProperty(access_token, ${access_token})}; in the setup postProcessor, using BeanShell instead of vars.put() ?

Comment: yes, you can save property in beanshell post-processor using `props.put` - see above, I edited the answer.

Comment: thanks, that works! quite a bummer i can't edit the header manager after the setup though.

Answer (score 3):

As per [Functions and Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) chapter of the JMeter User Manual

> Variables are local to a thread; properties are common to all threads, and need to be referenced using the [__P](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) or [__property](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__property) function

So the variable you define in the setUp Thread Group cannot be accessed by:

- other threads in the same Thread Group
- other threads outside the Thread Group

So my recommendations are:

1. Switch to JMeter Properties instead of Jmeter Variables, JMeter Properties are global to all threads and in fact the whole JVM instance
2. Switch to [JSR223 PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) with [Groovy](http://www.groovy-lang.org/) language instead of Beanshell PostProcessor, [JSR223 Elements performance is much better](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black), moreover [Groovy has built-in JSON support](http://groovy-lang.org/json.html).

So:

1. The relevant Groovy code for getting `access_token` attribute value and storing it into the relevant property would be :

   ```
   props.put('access_token', new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData()).access_token)
   ```
2. You can refer the value in the HTTP Header Manager (or wherever you require) as:

   ```
   ${__P(access_token,)}
   ```