# Unable to correlate value[token], from one sampler to another in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I have recorded script using BlazeMeter plugin and I want to the use access token which I receive in successful login request, in another request. My Test plan looks like as below

```
Thread Group : [A]
      |- HTTP Sampler - Login Page
           |-Regular Expression Extractor [getToken]
      |-HTTP Sampler - Other Page
           |-Beanshell PreProcessor[Set Header in Authorization]
```

1. Regular Expression Extractor parameters and values like below :

   ```
   Variable Name : token
   Regular Expression  : {“access_token”:”(.+?)"
   Template : $1$
   Match No. : 0
   ```
2. Beanshell PreProcessor script like below

   ```
   import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.Header;
   log.info("Start");
   sampler.getHeaderManager().add(new Header("Authorization","Bearer"+vars.get("token")));
   log.info(vars.get("token"));
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Most probably your Regular Expression Extractor fails as your quotation marks look utterly suspicious. You can double check if the `token` variable really has the anticipated value using [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) combination. Also check out [*jmeter.log* file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/hints_and_tips.html#debug_logging) for any suspicious entries, if your Beanshell script fails - the cause will be printed there.
2. The response data of the `Login Page` seems to be [JSON](https://www.w3schools.com/whatis/whatis_json.asp) therefore it makes sense to use the [JSON Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) instead of the Regular Expression Extractor. It allows using [JSON Path language](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#getting-started) in order to extract "interesting" bits of data from the responses. In your case the relevant JSON Path expression would be `$.access_token`
3. [Since JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) so consider migrating to the [JSR223 PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) and Groovy language (you can re-use the same code)
4. You don't even need the scripting, you can add [Authorization](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization) header (as well as any other header) using [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager)

Answer (score 0):

Could you add debug sampler and try first to confirm your regular expression extractor working as expected? It should provide you the required value of `token`.

If your `token` has the required value, I will suggest you to add `HTTP Header Manager` config element by right clicking on HTTP sampler

```
HTTP Request => Add => Config Element => HTTP Header Manager
```

In this config element, you can visually add the Headers as below:
[image: Sample image for HTTP Header Manager]

Please Note That:- You have not provided any **space/hyphen(-)** or between keyword Bear and token.

Refer this link for details :-
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24550552/1115090